# Error uploading a date object along with a string to a SQL db

Tags: python, sql

I have a `date object` that needs to be uploaded into a database from a `CSV` file. When I make a query to upload the row into DB. I get this error:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'of'. (156) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Code to upload data:

```
with open(UploadFile, "r") as uploadData:
    i = 0
    flag = 0
    formatter_string = "%d/%m/%y"
    for row in reader:
        if(flag == 0):
            flag = flag + 1
        else:
            datetime_object = datetime.strptime(row[0], formatter_string)
            row[0] = datetime_object.date()

        cursor.execute("insert into "+UploadTable+" values ("+row[0]+","+nullcheckstr(row[1])+","+nullcheckint(row[2])+","+nullcheckint(row[3])+","+nullcheckint(row[4])+","+nullcheckint(row[5])+","+nullcheckint(row[6])+","+nullcheckint(row[7])+","+nullcheckint(row[8])+")")
        print "insert into "+UploadTable+" values ("+str(row[0])+","+nullcheckstr(row[1])+","+nullcheckint(row[2])+","+nullcheckint(row[3])+","+nullcheckint(row[4])+","+nullcheckint(row[5])+","+nullcheckint(row[6])+","+nullcheckint(row[7])+","+nullcheckint(row[8])+")"
        i = i + 1
        print 'inserted ' + str(i) + ' rows'
    cnxn.commit()
```

`row[0]` is date

`nullcheckint/nullcheckstr`: checking if the row to be not null

Comment: hey what is check it. if it is null what are u doing it and what is flag here

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(UploadFile, "r") as uploadData:

    i=0
    flag=0
    formatter_string = "%d/%m/%y"
    d=[]
    for row in reader:
        if(flag==0):
            flag=flag+1
        else:
            datetime_object = datetime.strptime(row[0], formatter_string)
            row[0] = datetime_object.date()

        temp=[]
        for val,i in enumerate(row):
            if val==0:
                temp.append(str(row[0]))
            elif val == 1:
                temp.append(nullcheckstr(row[1]))
            else:
                temp.append(nullcheckint(row[1]))
        d.append(temp)

    for row in d:
        cursor.execute("insert into "+UploadTable+" values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",row)

        print 'inserted rows'


    cnxn.commit
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this code a try. Its a LOT cleaner and is easier to debug. Without knowing what your input file looks like, I have to assume the bug was in your jumbled code.

A few bugs/inconsistencies:

- You never use `uploadData`
- You never declare `reader`

---

```
with open(UploadFile, "r") as uploadData:
    i = 0

    # Since this is just a flag, use True/False
    flag = False
    formatter_string = "%d/%m/%y"
    for row in reader:
       if not flag:
            flag = True
       else:
            datetime_object = datetime.strptime(row[0], formatter_string)

            # Format each section of the row
            row[0] = datetime_object.date()
            row[1] = nullcheckstr(row[1])
            row[2:] = list(map(nullcheckint, row[2:]))

        # Use `str.format` to make this statement MUCH cleaner
        sql = "insert into {} values ({})".format(UploadTable, ','.join(row))
        cursor.execute(sql)

        i = i + 1

    print 'inserted {} rows'.format(str(i))
    cnxn.commit()
```